# TNS-00534: Failed to grant connection ownership to child

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c

when I tried to connect to my oracle instance with sql developer, I see this error in logs

```
TNS-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00534: Failed to grant connection ownership to child
   64-bit Windows Error: 10022: Unknown error
```

Can someone give me a poit how to solve this error. Note I have 64b client installed.

Comment: Sounds like there may be a problem with the Windows service account that is running the database. See here: https://nzdba.wordpress.com/2016/04/24/managed-service-account-vs-oracle-home-user/

Comment: It seems that this is not my problem. I configure oracle services to use Local account.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons could be:

1. There aren't enough processes to handle the request.
2. The accounts running Oracle DB and listener services are not the same.
3. Or, in my case, the server's hostname is over 15 characters.